# Custom policy add overlay message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using a custom policy for password change. I am following the custom policy mentioned here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Is there any way to add an orchestration step that displays overlay message that password has been changed before SendClaims step.

The User Journey as mentioned in the link:

```html
<UserJourney Id="PasswordChange">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
        <ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
    <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
  </UserJourney>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between step 4 and step 5, add an orchestration step to call a selfAsserted technical profile.

Demonstrated here:
Add a step (you can remove the preconditions node)
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L165

SelfAsserted technical profile with a message
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L110

You must have one output claim in the selfAsserted technical profile. Here a claim transform is used to generate a string to display to the user.

All options available to a self asserted page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile

Apply custom html to the page to deliver the message/branding
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I was able to successfully implement the selfAsserted technical profile using example steps provided by you. And using custom html I should be able to create a workable solution. Thank you!